# C#/LINQ select sublist of objects with same properties

Tags: c#, linq

I'm a beginner with LINQ and I would like to know if it is possible to use it to solve the following problem:

I have a class :

```
public class myClass
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Category { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of `myClass` objects.

```
public List<myClass> myList;
```

Can I easily get with LINQ the sublist of `myList` containing all the `myClass` objects for which the value of the property `Text` is present more than once.

for instance if I have

```
myClass A = new myClass { Id=1, Category=1, Text="Hello World!"};
myClass B = new myClass { Id=2, Category=2, Text="Hello World!"};
myClass C = new myClass { Id=3, Category=2, Text="Good Bye!"};
myList.AddRange(new []{ A, B, C });
```

I should have objects `A` and `B` in my sublist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps not ideal, but maybe:

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x=>x.Text).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
            .SelectMany(x=>x); // .ToList() if you want a list
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var result = from x in myList
             group x by x.Text into grp
             where grp.Count() > 1
             from y in grp
             select y; // .ToList() if you want a list
```

Comment: I vote for this one which works great indeed
and for the moment I prefer the query syntax, easier to understand for me :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
  var sublist = (from a in myList
                from b in myList
                where a.Text == b.Text
                   && a.Id != b.Id
                select a).Distinct();
```

---

Test Program:

```
void Main()
{

    myClass A = new myClass { Id=1, Category=1, Text="Hello World!"};
    myClass B = new myClass { Id=2, Category=2, Text="Hello World!"};
    myClass C = new myClass { Id=3, Category=2, Text="Good Bye!"};
    myClass D = new myClass { Id=4, Category=7, Text="Hello World!"};
    List<myClass> myList = new List<myClass>(); 
    myList.AddRange(new []{ A, B, C, D });

      var sublist = (from a in myList                
      from b in myList                
      where a.Text == b.Text                   
      && a.Id != b.Id                
      select a).Distinct();

      sublist.Dump();
}
public class myClass{  public int Id { get; set; }  public int Category { get; set; }  public string Text { get; set; }}
```

Comment: That works when there are 2 matches, but explodes when there are more; so 3 matches results in 6 results, etc.

Comment: @Marc - distinct added to fix :)